# Kernel Matching

Tags: causality, kernel-smoothing, propensity-scores, matching, treatment-effect

I wish to estimate a treatment effect using Kernel Matching, but I'm confused about the process. From a high level, Is **A** or **B** correct? Or are both considered Kernel matching?

**A**

(1) Estimate propensity scores

(2) Use kernel that uses the propensity scores to create weight matrix

(3) Calculate treatment effect using weights from matrix

**B**

(1) Compute distance between all observations (could be mahalanobis or euclidean), giving you a matrix of distances between observations

(2) Put distances through a kernel function, giving you a matrix of weights

(3) Calculate treatment effect using weights from matrix

I wish to code this up in R because there are no kernel matching functions that I'm aware of. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think package KBAL supports kernel balancing. However, I am afraid that the package was removed from R repository.